# How to play youtube, vimeo, amazon s3 bucket in Android Native Player?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, youtube, video-streaming

How to play youtube, vimeo, amazon s3 bucket video in Android Native Player?

I want play embedded video and simple video url like(.mp4, .m3u8) both in Android native player so, is there way to play video on same.

Comment: I had many research behind this,  but I did not got any proper solution as a play all kinds of third party embed url in same Android native player.

Comment: Now, I am using better approach

Answer (score 2):

Now, I am using better approach, when i want to play Youtube video then i am using youtube player provided by youtube Api.

- Other third party embedded url parse as per given standard.
- For Native Player, I use customize media player.